# touchmove event won't fire after scaling image (scale3d)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, scale, css-transforms, touchmove

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/hWm9M/1/
by doing a `touchmove` while the image is scaling, you can verify in the console that the `touchmove` event is attached as expected. But when fully scaled, the event won't fire.
I tried to attach the event on transitionend, but it didn't worked either.

Here is the code:

```
var handleStart = function() {
    this.style.webkitTransition = 'all 3s linear'
    this.style.webkitTransform = 'scale3d(2, 2, 0)'
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false)
}

var handleMove = function() {
    console.log(this)
}

var image = document.getElementById("img")
image.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false)
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's simpler to handle the touchmove all the time (you add evt list once after the touchstart handler), and to have a boolean tell you if your transition is ongoing. Rq : Your code might add several times an event listener/trigger several transforms (multitouch case).

Comment: Like that http://jsfiddle.net/53kd8/1/ ?
The problem really seem to be linked to the use of scale3d. I tried to use translate3d for testing and the event keeps firing after the transition.

Comment: well if the situation is that clear (ok with translate3d, buggy with scale3d), you might just have found a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens when you use scale3d with the Z value == 0

a work arround i use is passing 1 instead of 0 to the Z value:

in your case something like: 'scale3d(2, 2, 1)'